# ngOptions not binding model to data.

Tags: angularjs, angular-ngmodel, ng-options, angularjs-ng-options, angularjs-select

I am rendering a drop down list with ngOptions. This is how the view looks like:

```
<select>
<option ng-repeat="gender in vm.genderArray" ng-model="vm.genderOfPerson" ng-change="vm.changingGender()"> {{gender.gender}} </option>
</select>
```

In the controller, this is what I am doing:

```
vm.genderArray = [{gender: "Please select one"},{gender: "Male"},{gender: "Female"},{gender: "Would rather not say"}]
function changingGender() {
  console.log("vm.user.gender")
}
```

Here's the problem statement no: 
I want to save the value of the changed gender in *vm.user.gender* .. but it is not getting saved in that.

Please look over the code and tell me what am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: If you want it in vm.user.gender, then use `ng-model=vm.user.gender` and not `ng-model="vm.genderOfPerson"`.

Answer (score 1):

```
 <select ng-options="p.gender  for p in vm.genderArray" 
            ng-model="vm.selectedPerson">
    </select>
    <p>You selected {{vm.selectedPerson.gender}}</p>
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sajeetharan/j4sayxsx/1/)**